# Issue saving matplotlib plot with artist

Tags: matplotlib, save, patch

I used the following code to generate [image: this windrose:] The wind rose shares an axis with the artists which are Wedge patches.

```
fov = Wedge((0.51,0.43), 0.497, 174.5, 202.5, lw=1.5, facecolor="grey", edgecolor ='black', transform=ax.transAxes, alpha=0.2)

fov1 = Wedge((0.51,0.43), 0.497, 174.5, 202.5, lw=1.5, fill=None, edgecolor ='black', transform=ax.transAxes, alpha=1)

plt.hist([0, 1])
plt.close()
ax=WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.grid(linestyle="dashed", color="grey", zorder=0)
ax.bar(df['dir'], df['w_speed'],normed=True, opening=1, cmap = cm.magma_r, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, bins=spd_bins, nsector=36, zorder= 3)
ax.set_legend(loc=(-0.12, 0.75), labels=spd_labels)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(1, 12, step=3))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(1, 12, step=3))
ax.add_artist(fov)
ax.add_artist(fov1)
plt.savefig(fname)
plt.show()
```

The plot includes an artists which gets moved when I save the figure in either of .pdf, .jpeg, .png, .eps formats. [image: The saved version of this figure is provided here in .eps format.]

Comment: Can you include the rest of your code? As it is `ax` appears to be referenced before assignment

Comment: Indeed the wedge is transformed according to an axes which isn't part of the code that is shown. That also explains why it's in the wrong position.

Comment: This is the full code... ax is defined by: ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax(). The package I used was called using: from windrose import WindroseAxes.

Comment: No. If this was the full code it would throw an error, because in the first line you *use* `ax`, but you define it only *after* that.

Comment: Well this is indeed the full code... and it does not return any kind of error message. But I understand what you are saying... let me try to define the artists after I define the axes.

Comment: Hi! you were right... I was using ax. to draw a different plot earlier in my code and I guess it just connected to that! Problem solved! Thanks for raising the issue! Though... when I use the .eps format... the color still changes.. as if alpha was set to 1... Would you know why?